# Using opensubtitles api Node.js/Python wrapper behind a proxy

Tags: python, node.js, proxy, xml-rpc, subtitle

I'm trying to use [opensubtitles-api](https://github.com/vankasteelj/opensubtitles-api) node.js wrapper of opensubtitles api behind a proxy. Unfortunately there is no proxy option available. The library in turn uses [node-xmlrpc](https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc) to make RPC calls. But the underlying `node-xmlrpc` library also doesn't support proxy tunneling. My project also benefits from some `python` libraries and code. But [python](https://github.com/agonzalezro/python-opensubtitles) wrapper also seems not to handle proxies. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `node-xmlrpc` is using [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)/[https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) you can specify a proxy like this.

```
const xmlrpc  = require('xmlrpc');

const options = {
  host: "proxy_url",
  port: 8080, // proxy port
  path: "http://opensubtitles_url",
  headers: {
    Host: "opensubtitles_domain",
    "Proxy-Authorization": "Basic bXl1c2VyOm15cGFzc3dvcmQ=" // if needed
  }
};

const client  = xmlrpc.createClient(options);
```